# Why am I getting this error in python--> NameError: name 'FloatTensorType' is not defined

Tags: python

```html
initial_type = [('numfeat', FloatTensorType([None, 3])),
                ('strfeat', StringTensorType([None, 2]))]
model_onnx = convert_sklearn(model, initial_types=initial_type)
```

Why am I getting the error 
NameError: name 'FloatTensorType' is not defined 
in python?

Comment: Probably you have something wrong with importing, What is  1.List item ?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], as well as the entire error message.

Answer (score 0):

You have to import FloatTensorType:

```
from onnxmltools.convert.sparkml.utils import FloatTensorType
```

Answer (score -1):

Double check versions of all installed ONNX libraries. They should be > 1.7.0